# Reusing queries and the include method

Tags: entity-framework

We have a complicated LINQ to entities query and for redundancy reasons we would like to reuse the query.

An example to illustrate our problem:

```
var query = from x in context.Building.Include("Kitchen")
          select x;
```

In another use case, we want to eager load the "Bedroom"

```
var query = from x in context.Building.Include("Bedroom")
          select x;
```

Is it possible to add or change the **Include** stuff later?
I am looking for something like this:

```
var query = from x in context.Building select x;
query.AddInclude("Kitchen");
query.AddIncldue("Other stuff");
```

How do you do query reuse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either download EF 4.1 and use its strongly typed extensions to `IQueryable` or try to write `AddInclude` like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> AddInclude(this IQueryable<T> query, string include)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(include))
    {
        throw new ArgumetNullException("include");
    }

    var objectQuery = query as ObjectQuery<T>;

    if (objectQuery == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    return objectQuery.Include(include);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good thing that they added strongly typed extensions to IQueryable<T>. The Include method is for ObjectSet and not for ObjectQuery in 4.0. So the answer to the question is NO (Is it possible to add or change the Include stuff later). I hoped there is another way.